# Hangouts Icons Meanings

Tags: google-hangouts, notification-icons

I know when someone reads your message, their picture in mini appears after the last message. Here's where I'm confused:

1. If it's shaded, that means they're not currently looking at your particular conversation?
2. There's a mini cell phone icon that appears beside the mini picture. It seems to appear randomly. Does it simply mean that they answered your hangout via cell phone? Or does it mean that they are currently using hangouts with another conversation (if the mini picture remains shaded)?

Answer (score 3):

If there is a computer next to their icon, it means they are on a PC (or Chromebook).

If there is a phone, they are on their phone. The position of their icon shows the last message they read.

If the icon is dim, it means they are not looking at your message. Doesn't mean that hangouts is open, or closed.